# Create Speedometer type layout

Tags: android

I want to create a layout like this in my android app,on whichever smiley user clicks,arrow should be pointed over that and that feedback should be recorded.Also user should be able to rotate arrow too over the smileys.Please help me.Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this option is suitable for your problem.

You can create a view extending for instance from LinearLayout, init it with a custom layout with your speedometer and the arrow. Finally internally you can manage the arrow rotation according your needs.

In this way you can use it later in a xml layout file without problem.